# call to undefined method Request::getParam?

Tags: model-view-controller, request, dispatcher

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Request::getParam() in C:\wamp\www\Admin\corporate\for-upload\activecollab\application\modules\system\controllers\CompaniesController.class.php on line 219

in controller class I've written

`$this->request->getParam('is_owner');`

and in request I've passed

```
$router->map('people_companies_add_owner', 'people/add-owner-company/is_owner','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'add_owner','is_owner'=>'true'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method "**getParam**" in the Request class.

There is one method "**get**" is available in the Request class.

So, instead of using "getParam" method use "get" method of Request class that will solve this issue.

:HTH